# Python 3 installed and unable to install MySQLdb due to 2.7 deprecation error

Tags: python, installation, mysql-python

I've got python 3 installed

```
spiders$ python -V
Python 3.8.5
```

And when I attempt to install MYSQLD I get the following message:

```
spiders$ pip install mysqlclient
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

I see that this might be due to the python directory under which Pip sits. But I'm incredibly uneducated about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using `python -m pip install mysqlclient` - looks like the wrong `pip` is being found.

Comment: same error I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install mysql-connector-python` fixed it.